# How to convert a stream in a string builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-functions

I have a Blob trigger and in that a stream object is there. I want to pass the content/text to a httpclinet post call. How can i do that?

I am having a csv file with 3 lines of data each column is separated by comma

Content in my CSV :

```
File1,121,12123,5676,fgfg,gfg,fg,
File2,ertet,etert,ert,
File3,354345,345345
```

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("expenses/{name}.csv", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream inputBlob, string name,
    [Table("Expenses", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] IAsyncCollector<Expense> expenseTable,
    ILogger log)
{
```

Here want to convert the stream `inputBlob` to string/string builder and want to get the result same as the data which is there in the file.

After that I want to call an (PostAsync call) API with content-type : text/csv and the data mentioned above. I read about httplient.  If I am using `HttpClient` how do I pass the content-type and the req body

Comment: your question is not clear at all. Please show relevant code that you have tried so far and any errors etc. that you hit

Comment: `StreamReader`?

Comment: @Amy Sorry i didnt get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you can use `StreamReader`, code snippet like below:

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("expenses/{name}.csv", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream inputBlob, string name,
    [Table("Expenses", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] IAsyncCollector<Expense> expenseTable,
    ILogger log)
    {

        //your other code

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myBlob))
        {
            string my_content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
    }
```

For your 2nd question, when you use HttpClient, then add the following code to your function:

```
  [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("expenses/{name}.csv", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream inputBlob, string name,
    [Table("Expenses", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] IAsyncCollector<Expense> expenseTable,
    ILogger log)
    {

     //your other code.

     //here, use the HttpClient

     //define the http verb
     var method = new HttpMethod("POST"); 

     //add the content to body
     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
      {
            Content = new StringContent("your string to post")
      };

      //add content type
      request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/csv"));

      //send
      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
      var result = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

    }
```

Comment: How do i add boundary in this request

Comment: @jubi, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500040/httpclient-setting-boundary-with-content-type?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I would like to follow your code. how do i include the boundary in ur code

Comment: My question is should i remover equest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/csv"));

Comment: @jubi, I just did try using httpClient without boundary(since I'm not familiar with this boundary header). can you please take a try at your side?